# What's the easiest way to merge edges in blender?

Tags: edges

In the picture below I have 3 edges (on the left) I select the middle one and move it up so that's where I am now- the one on the right. But I'm wondering how to merge the 3 edges with the one on the top so it's just one single edge. I want it to keep the two-front cuts in it as well (basically I want it to look like the right one except the edges are actually merged and not overlapping.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create 2 edges on your top face:

[image]

You can move them along the face with the slide tool (<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>) and snap to the bottom vertices position so that you're sure they are aligned with them:

[image]

Then merge the vertices:

[image]

Comment: is there some way to calculate the same exact distance of the cuts on the top plane so when I merge the vertices the line doesn't become diagonal?

Comment: Please see my edit, is it what you want to know?

Comment: yea that's perfect thank you very much!